# Axios not working on localhost Vue.js but working on external APIs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Whenever I use axios with external APIs, it grabs the data correctly and puts it into the `info` variable.

But whenever I try to use this on my own localhost environment, it doesn't return anything and there are no console errors to be seen.

vue js

```
 <script type="module">

        new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data() {
                return {
                    info: null
                }
            },
            mounted: function () {
                axios
                    .get("https://localhost:44331/Api/ShowRecipes/test/test") 
                    .then(response => this.info = response.data.bpi)
            }
        })

    </script>
```

api response json

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "IngredientName": "something",
    "IngredientCategory": "other",
    "Calories": 100
  },
```

html

```
<div id="app">
   @RenderBody()
   {{ info }}
</div>
```

And so on. Is this due to that you can't test it on localhost? Or did I do something wrong in my api?

Comment: Hi, your request is using https in your local environment, try to use http if you doesn't have the https configuration. Also, you can use postman to verify that the endpoint is working fine.

Comment: @andres Hi thank you for your reply, if I use http the url wont anymore. I verified with postman that the api does infact return json data. I did however need to make sure sure that ssl certificate checking was off.

Comment: I mean, try to use http in your local environment `http://localhost:44331/Api/ShowRecipes/test/test`, if you have a ssl certificated to serve the application locally, then check it as you suggested :D

Comment: Hmm tried using it but it loads forever when I do, unlike with https when it goes instantly

Comment: Using postman for request `http://localhost:44331/Api/ShowRecipes/test/test`, takes the same time?, does you have any response from `https://localhost:44331/Api/ShowRecipes/test/test` with postman? (take into account the http and https)

Comment: When I use postman with https I get the response I expect, but whenever I use http it loads infinitely. This also happens on my application itself

Comment: Is there any error in the console? Go to `Network` tab in dev console and check if the request is made and what the response looks like. You're likely facing a CORS issue. Also, when testing with postman, are you using any particular headers? Look closely at both requests (the one in postman and the one in vue) at both payload and headers and figure out what's different.

Comment: @tao Sorry for the late reply. I've checked the network tab and I can see that it does return a json response which I want with a status code of 200. I don't use any headers to retrieve the information. I do see in the headers tab that there is a header type of `content-type: application/json` and `accept: application/json`

Comment: If it returns the json with 200 the problem is in your app. You're not parsing the result properly. Change `.then(response => this.info = response.data.bpi)` to `.then(response => console.log(response))` and figure out what's wrong. Obviously, it doesn't have whatever it is you're expecting in `data.bpi`. Is there any chance the response is a string instead of it being a proper json object? because `'{"foo":"bar"}'`'s `.foo` is `undefined` while `{"foo":"bar"}`'s  `.foo` is `"bar"`.

Comment: @tao Thank you! I managed to fix it. I needed to remove the .bpi, which wasn't needed